# The word order of indirect questions

Tags: reported-speech

Stumbled upon this passage reading Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage* (highly commendable book):

> End-weight can also affect the word order of indirect questions. Compare:
>   I'm not sure **what the point is**.
>   I'm not sure **what is the point** of spending hours and hours discussing this.

It seems the second sentence goes against the rule governing the word order of an indirect question (no inversion!). Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that's what's in the book? It'd be fine without "I'm not sure"...

Comment: Of course, I am - the quotation is from a pdf copy of the book.

Comment: I think this is a special case of [heavy NP shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift). That would normally give rise to "... what the point is of spending ... ", but something about _is_ tends to move it further to the left.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the book is incorrect.

The second phrase should either invert as the first example or the beginning of the sentence should be removed:

> I'm not sure what the point is of spending hours and hours discussing this.
>   What is the point of spending hours and hours discussing this?

Either of these two are correct, though the second is not an indirect question.

Comment: Are you going to argue with M.Swan about grammar? hehe
This is definitely NOT a typo and that's why it's so baffling.

Comment: This would be correct:  "I'm not sure _what_ is the point of spending hours and hours discussing this."  (Rather a sarcastic and hostile phrase to employ as a usage model, though.)

Comment: @MvLog Clearly... for all we know, this is simply a misprint in the book. It has been known to happen.

Comment: @ Catija A misprint which has got a special paragraph devoted to this "misprint"? Read this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116992/indirect-be-question-word-order , and this http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81606/whats-in-indirect-questions

Comment: this answer seems to be more or less plausible http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51123/im-not-sure-what-the-right-way-is/51126#comment94968_51126

Comment: @MvLog Those first two, at the least agree with me... it just sounds wrong. Perhaps it's OK to some people in some areas but as an AmE speaker... it's not a good usage.

Comment: Right now am reading http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/private-language/#Pre .... and here we are....  _The attempt to name a sensation in a conceptual vacuum merely raises the **questions of what this business is supposed to consist in, and what is its point**._

Comment: @MvLog "what this business is supposed to consist **in**" doesn't make sense. "Consist of" is the standard. Also, a completely different usage than your example quote. Regardless... Please stop commenting on my answer. It's annoying me. If you really don't like it, downvote and wait for someone else to respond.

Comment: I wonder if this is a case of UK vs. US English.  I see that Michael Swan is British, and perhaps this is a more normal usage there, but it sounds wrong to this American.